# Is there a way to extract values from a database using mongoose and store the desired results into a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose

The goal I wish to achieve is to search into my database find the results that I require and store it into a variable so that I can use it at a later stage in the program.

I have created new person and successfully saved it to my database as per the code below:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testClubDB", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });

const nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String
});

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", nameSchema);

const person = new Person({
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe"
});

person.save(function(err){
    if(!err){
        console.log("Successfully added to DB");
    }
});
```

Thus, in my database there is the following entry:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60dd9a95e6eed847b4c985ba"),
    "name" : "John",
    "surname" : "Doe",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I am familiar with Model.find() from mongoose which gets the following:

```js
Person.find({name:"John"}, function(err, info){
    if(!err){
        info.forEach(function(x){
            var value1 = x.name;
            var value2 = x.surname;
            var data = [value1, value2];
            console.log(data); // this appears in the console ["John","Doe"]
        });
};
```

Now I wish to return this data and store it into a variable, below is an example of how I hoped would of achieved this:

```js
function getQueryData(name){
    Person.find({name:name}, function(err, info){
        if (!err){
            info.forEach(function(x){
                var value1 = x.name;
                var value2 = x.surname;
                var data = [value1, value2];
                return data
            });
        }
    });
}


var result = getQueryData("John");

console.log(result); // I was expecting ["John", "Doe"] but get undefined
```

But the above resulted in result = undefined, so instead I tried using an async function as below:

```js
async function getQueryData(name){
    values = await Person.find({name:name}, function(err, info){
        if (!err){
            info.forEach(function(x){
                var value1 = x.name;
                var value2 = x.surname;
                var data = [value1, value2];
            });
        }
    });
}


var result = getQueryData("John");

console.log(result); // It now displays in the console: Promise { <pending> }
```

So now I am really uncertain what is happening (I am fairly new to programming and coding, before anyone judges). I thought perhaps adding a .then() could help, but this is what happened:

```js
var result = getQueryData("John");
result.then((goal) => {
    console.log(goal); // I get two things in my console, Promise pending and undefined. I am guessing this resulted in the Promise pending
});

console.log(result); // and this resulted in the undefined
```

Now I am at my wits end and have now resorted to asking for help. If anybody has any suggestions on what I can do to solve this problem, it will be greatly appreciated!

PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE HELP!

I tried using Model.findOne() as follows:

```js
async function getQueryData(name){
    values = await Person.findOne({name:name}, function(err, info){
        if (!err){
            var data = [info.name, info.surname]
        }
    });
}


var result = getQueryData("John");
result.then((goal) => {
    console.log(goal);
});

console.log(result); // However, still resulted in Promise pending and undefined in the console
```

Comment: mongoose `Model.find()` returns an array. Use `findOne(...)`. Also, you don't need callback when using `async\await`.

Answer (score 0):

When calling an asynchronous function, you generally want to put await before it e.g.

```
let foo = async () => "Foo!";
let stringWithoutAwait = foo(); // Promise;
let stringWithAwait = await foo(); // "Foo"
```

Some tasks, like calls to the database, can take a long time. But if your server had to stop serving other users every time you needed something from the database, it would be a terrible server. That's why asynchronous functions were invented.

An async function returns immediately, even before it's gotten the answer, so that your code can keep executing. Instead of the answer, it returns a Promise to give you the answer later. If you want to pause and wait until the Promise is resolved, aka, the function finally has the answer, then you need to "await" the async function with the await keyword.

So your code should read like this:

```
let result = await Person.findOne({name: "John"});
console.log(result);
```

Also, you can only use the await keyword inside another asynchronous function, so be careful of that.